# Swapping 2d array minimum row value with reverse diagonal

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, swap

I am trying to swap minimum row value with reverse diagonal. I managed to print out every row minimum value, but my swap fails. Maybe you could give me some hints.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
        int min = mas[i][0];
         for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)
         {
             if (mas[i][j] < min)
             {
                min = mas[i][j];
             }
             for(int k=n-1;k>0;k--){
                for(int h = m-1; h>0;h--){

                min = mas[i][j];
                mas[i][j]=mas[k][h];
                mas[k][h]=min;
             }
             cout << "New Matrix\n";
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
             }
         }
    }        
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is my `for` for a minimum value and later I am adding another `for` to swap values.

My result:
I go printed out 3 matrices and none of them are correctly swapping value. I guess it's because of for in for cycle?

My file with with 2d array:

```
1 2 5 // row min 1, reverse diagonal 5
2 8 9 // row min 2, reverse diagonal 8
5 9 10 // row min 5, revese diagonal 5
```

What output I expect:

```
5 2 1 // 5 diagonal swap with min = 1
8 2 9 // 8 diagonal swap with min = 2
5 9 10 // 5 diagonal no swap because 5 is row minimum
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your input data and how it should look after you process it?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have added more code.

Comment: @NotsoPr0 One more show the source array and the result array. Otherwise it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I have added what I am trying to do

Comment: @NotsoPr0 I am not going to repeat the same the third time.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I added what I am expecting, my generated array and expecting results array. You want to look what I am getting after compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly then the "reverse diagonal" can be present only in a square matrix. So there is no sense to enter two values `n` and `m` to deal with a square matrix.

If to consider the example of a 3 x 3 matrix shown in your question and to use loops instead of for example standard functions `std::max_element` and `std::swap` then the code that converts the matrix can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 3;
    int a[N][N] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 5 },
        { 2, 8, 9 },
        { 5, 9, 10 }
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << a[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        size_t min = 0;
        for (size_t j = 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] < a[i][min]) min = j;
        }

        if ( min != N - i - 1 )
        {
            int tmp = a[i][min];
            a[i][min] = a[i][N - i - 1];
            a[i][N - i - 1] = tmp;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << a[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
 1  2  5
 2  8  9
 5  9 10

 5  2  1
 8  2  9
 5  9 10
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. It is exactly what I want to get.